# Ubuntu Virtual Host served by Cloudflare is displaying a 521 error

Tags: apache2

I am in the process of transferring a number of sites to a new server. I've moved two already and after lots of issues these two are displaying fine on the new server. I'm using Cloudflare and have updated the DNS so the Virtual Host displays the sites from the new server.

At first I update the DocumentRoot in /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

For the problem site it then displays fine using the server ip address.

I have done a2ensite and can see the conf file in sites-enabled. My VirtualHost file is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    
    ServerAdmin webmaster@saddleworthwi.com
    ServerName saddleworthwi.com
    ServerAlias www.saddleworthwi.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/saddleworthwi.com/public_html

    <Directory "/var/www/saddleworthwi.com/public_html">
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

But if I change the Cloudflare DNS I get the 521 Error when trying to access the site using the domain name. If I switch the path in the Virtual Host to /var/www/html. I get the same error.

Not sure why two other sites work using essentially the same VirtualHost conf file, just with changed DocumentRoot, ServerName and Alias.

Any suggestions.

Comment: General help for 5xx errors: read the error log.

Comment: No errors relating to this appearing using tail -10 /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: What's in your error log? What's in access log?

Comment: Several lines like this 195.20.254.172 - - [26/Dec/2023:10:37:56 +0000] "POST /wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1703587076.5429050922393798828125 HTTP/1.1" 200 243 "-" "WordPress/6.4.2; https://saddleworthwi.com" in access.log
and
[Tue Dec 26 09:08:37.087151 2023] [php:warn] [pid 53361] [client 198.235.24.251:49956] PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "host" in /var/www/saddleworthwi.com/public_html/wp-includes/canonical.php on line 718
in error.log
But I still get a 521 if I switch the VirtualHost DocumentRoot to /var/www/html